# What's the "ridge" in Ridge Regression?

Tags: statistics, terminology, regression

In normal least squares, we try to find $\hat\beta$ which minimizes
$$\|y-X\beta\|^2$$
Ridge regression expands this to "penalize" certain values of $\beta$ via a matrix $\Gamma$:
$$\|y-X\beta\|^2+\|\Gamma\beta\|^2$$
I'm wondering where the term "ridge" comes from. My best guess is that it has something to do with a geometric interpretation of the term $\Gamma$, but I can't find anything written about this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in this [link](http://jarad.me/stat615/papers/Ridge_Regression_in_Practice.pdf) (page 5, col.2), Hoerl (presumably the inventor of ridge regression)

"*gave the name "ridge regression" to his procedure because of the similarity of its mathematics to methods he used earlier i.e., "ridge analysis," for graphically depicting the characteristics of second order response surface equations in many predictor variables.*"

In this link you can also find the name of the original paper of Hoerl [9]. So, in my interpretation the name is more due to the similarity of the method to earlier work of it's inventor rather due to it's characteristics.

Comment: I think the name "Shrinkage estimation" is more appropriate than ridge regression.  The magnitude of the original regression coefficients is "shrunk" towards zero, hence the term shrinkage is more appropriate. The word "ridge" is used in discussing the optimality conditions (i.e., first-and second- order KKT) for nonlinear optimization. When the gradient of the objective function is zero, but the Hessian is indefinite, then the surface of the objective function is said to resemble a ridge.